# How to have Frea forgive me

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

While on a quest in Solstheim, I killed some wild animals. Some hunters arrived, and I kill them, like I normally do in the main Skyrim area.

Apparently, this made Frea and all the Skaal mad, they keep trying to kill me and I cant even get past the first mission.

I cannot go back to an earlier save. Please someone tell me how to have her stop trying to kill me so I can talk to her. And also tell me how I can make the other Skaal friendly again.

I'm playing on the Xbox 360. During the [Fate of the Skaal](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:The_Fate_of_the_Skaal) quest.

Comment: are you on pc? there are certain console commands that might help. also it would be helpful to know the name of the quest. I'm assuming its fate of the skaal?

Comment: Xbox 360 and yeah Fate of the skaal

Comment: well that makes it a bit tougher. there are a few things you can try however. try going to raven rock and waiting there for 24 hours and going back to the village. if that doesn't work then try committing a petty crime in raven rock and going to jail. one of those might work, but its not guaranteed. let me know if they do and i'll make this an answer you can accept, otherwise i'll try and research another way to fix it for you

Comment: And just so you know that's 24 hours in in game time, aka using the wait command. Just thought I'd clarify that in case you weren't familiar with it.